# LeafletJS how to display HTML Elements/DIV/Input Box/Button on specific position using LongLat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, leaflet

I'd like to ask about if it is possible or how do I add a "HTML Element" on spefic location on the map using Long Lat?

My goal is to add a Label and Text Input or a Text and Button pair sort of thing of specific position on the map.

Like for example:

Displaying a html + css control that displays a name and hobby:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr6GK.png)

Given the longitude and latitude place it on the map.

Is there a way doing this? How to do this?
Then maybe add something like a alert when clicking it.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options:

- Using [`L.popup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup)'s
- Using [`L.tooltip`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tooltip)'s
- Using an [`L.marker`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) with an [`L.divIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon)

Example:

```js
var popup = L.popup({
    closeButton: false,
    autoClose: false,
    closeOnClick: false
  })
  .setLatLng([48.85, 2.30])
  .setContent(makeHtml(0));

var tooltip = L.tooltip({
    permanent: true,
    direction: 'left'
  })
  .setLatLng([48.84, 2.34])
  .setContent(makeHtml(1));

var divIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: makeHtml(2),
  className: 'divIcon',
  iconSize: [200, 50],
  iconAnchor: [0, 0]
});

var marker = L.marker([48.85, 2.35], {
  icon: divIcon
});

var map = L.map('map').setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

popup.openOn(map);
map.openTooltip(tooltip);
marker.addTo(map);

function makeHtml(id) {
  return '<label for="input_' + id + '">Input:</label><input type="text" value="my value…" id="input_' + id + '" />'
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}

.divIcon {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think about one way. I've used the `L.divIcon` for the same purpose. Here is a part of my code :

```
var yourPoint = L.divIcon({
  className: 'map-marker-yourClassHere',
  iconSize: null,
  iconAnchor:   [17, 35],
  html:'<div class="text-marker">'+ txt +'</div>'
});
L.marker(latlng, {icon: yourPoint}).addTo(map);
```

You can simply put everything you want into this html option.